# There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code ServiceUnavailable

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, slack

I'm trying to test a ChatBot using Microsoft Azure. However, the bot is not working in the "Test in Web Chat" feature and it throws this error:

*There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code ServiceUnavailable*

Anyone know why? I've hypothesised that it's because I am on an unpaid version of Azure, but I want to be sure before I upgrade.

Also, I'm testing the API endpoing on the Bot Framework Emulator, and it throws a POST 503 error (Service Unavailable).

Comment: I don't think this is related to paid version. The endpoint you are trying to access, is it accessible by public internet?

Comment: Yep, it is. I don't think its related to paid version either, turns out theres quite a bit of credit in the account to start off with.

Comment: Can it be your firewall, it says you need to 'Allow Access' : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/test/test-bots-in-web-chat?tabs=v2x

Comment: What endpoint you are trying in emulator ? Is it LUIS or some other endpoint ? Could you please elaborate the steps and bot language that you are tried in your application.

Comment: Can you double check if you have followed all the [deployment steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)? A similar issue was reported [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/72356/deployment-to-azure-fails.html)